# Python/Pandas - Read multiple files in a folder based on dates in filenames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with hundreds of csv files with the filenames in the format of file_nameddmmyyyy (e.g. data25062019.csv).

I am using python/pandas to read the files and manipulating the dataframes. I want to be able to pull multiple csv files based on the dates on the file names. 
e.g. I want to open the daily files from the previous one week and append them to a dataframe.

The problem is there are not files for everyday of the week, so there may only be 4-5 files for the last week.

Any suggestions on best way to approach this?

Comment: List all files in the directory, grab the last 8 characters before `.csv`, convert to a date, check if it's within the past week, then read only those files.

Comment: Thank you. Got it working using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the read command in a try except statement:

`try:
    read_file()
    append_file()
 except:
     pass`